# How to minimize a non-linear function with constraints in c#?

Tags: c#, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I would like to minimize the following function

[image]

with constraints

[image: $$w_i \geq 0, \sqrt{w_1^2 + w_2^2} = 1$$]

in C#. I tried to do it with [Math.Net's Newton Method](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Optimization/NewtonMinimizer.htm), but I can't figure out how to do it. How can I minimize the function programmatically in C# for given $F_1, F_2$?

Update:
After the comment of @MinosIllyrien I tried the following, but I don't get the syntax:

```
_f1 = 0.3; // Global fields.
_f2 = 0.7;

var minimizer = new NewtonMinimizer(1E-4, 100, false);
var objectiveFunction = ObjectiveFunction.ScalarDerivative(FunctionToMinimize, GradientOfFunctionToMinimize);
var firstGuess = CreateVector.DenseOfArray(new[] {0.5});
var minimalWeight1 = minimizer.FindMinimum(objectiveFunction, firstGuess).MinimizingPoint;

private double GradientOfFunctionToMinimize(double w1){
  return _f1 - (w1 * _f2) / Math.Sqrt(1 - Math.Pow(w1, 2));
}

private double FunctionToMinimize(double w1){
  return w1 * _f1 + Math.Sqrt(1 - Math.Pow(w1, 2)) * _f2;
}
```

This does not work, because FindMinimum method requires IObjectiveFunction as function and not IScalarObjectiveFunction...

**Update 2:**
I tried a solution from [Google](https://developers.google.com/optimization/lp/lp_example):

```
var solver = Solver.CreateSolver("GLOP");
Variable w1 = solver.MakeNumVar(0.0, double.PositiveInfinity, "w1");
Variable w2 = solver.MakeNumVar(0.0, double.PositiveInfinity, "w2");

solver.Add(Math.Sqrt(w1*w1 + w2*w2) == 1);
```

This throws the error that *-operator cannot be used for "Variable" and "Variable". Someone any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? It may help to re-write the contraints to w2 = sqrt(1 - w1^2) such that y = w1*F1 + sqrt(1 - w1^2)*F2. That way, it's only a 1-parameter search for w1 in the interval [0, 1].

Comment: Are F1 and F2 constants?

Comment: I tried to implement the Newton Method, but I don't know how to formulate the problem.
Yes, F1 and F2 are constants.

Comment: Just a crazy idea: isn't this equivalent to finding a minimum for _f(x)_ = _F1_ cos _x_ + _F2_ sin _x_ ?

Comment: You don't need optimisation for this - just find the gradient of y and pick the point on the unit circle in that direction (or one of (1,0) and (0,1)).

Comment: Ruud Helderman I don't see the connection.
@Mark Pattison I don't know the direction, because I need to find it via optimization, right? My maths knowledge is rusty...

Answer (score 0):

*w*₁² + *w*₂² = 1 is basically the [unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle).
The unit circle can also be described by the following [parametric equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation):

> (cos *t*, sin *t*)

In other words, for every pair (*w*₁, *w*₂),
there is an angle *t* for which *w*₁ = cos *t* and *w*₂ = sin *t*.

With that substitution, the function becomes:

> *y* = *F*₁ cos *t* + *F*₂ sin *t*

*w*₁ ≥ 0, *w*₂ ≥ 0 restricts *t* to a single quadrant. This leaves you with a very simple constraint, that consists of a single variable:

> 0 ≤ *t* ≤ ½π

By the way, the function can be [simplified](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2085687) to:

> *y* = *R* cos(*t* - α)

where *R* = √(*F*₁² + *F*₂²) and α = [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)(*F*₂, *F*₁)

This is a simple sine wave. Without the constraint on *t*, its range would be [-*R*, *R*], making the minimum -*R*. But the constraint limits the domain and thereby the range:

- If *F*₁ < 0 and *F*₂ < 0, then the minimum is at *w*₁ = -*F*₁ / *R*, *w*₂ = -*F*₂ / *R*, with *y* = -*R*
- For 0 < *F*₁ ≤ *F*₂, a minimum is at *w*₁ = 1, *w*₂ = 0, with *y* = *F*₁
- For 0 < *F*₂ ≤ *F*₁, a minimum is at *w*₁ = 0, *w*₂ = 1, with *y* = *F*₂

Notes:

- if *F*₁ = *F*₂ > 0, then you have two minima.
- if *F*₁ = *F*₂ = 0, then *y* is just flat zero everywhere.

In code:

```
_f1 = 0.3;
_f2 = 0.7;

if (_f1 == 0.0 && _f2 == 0.0) {
    Console.WriteLine("Constant y = 0 across the entire domain");
}
else if (_f1 < 0.0 && _f2 < 0.0) {
    var R = Math.sqrt(_f1 * _f1 + _f2 * _f2);
    Console.WriteLine($"Minimum y = {-R} at w1 = {-_f1 / R}, w2 = {-_f2 / R}");
}
else {
    if (_f1 <= _f2) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Minimum y = {_f1} at w1 = 1, w2 = 0");
    }
    if (_f1 >= _f2) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Minimum y = {_f2} at w1 = 0, w2 = 1");
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll also need to check that both w1 and w2 are non-negative.  If not, the solution will be either (0,1) or (1,0).

Comment: @MarkPattison Thank you for pointing this out; I edited my answer accordingly.